# How to compare selected UIPickerView row element to Array element?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var categoryFactsPincker: UIPickerView!

    @IBOutlet weak var randomFactLabel: UILabel!
```

This is my array of my UIPickerView

```
let categoryFactsArray = ["Interesting Facts", "Fun Facts", "Nutrition Facts", "Funny Facts", "Unbelievable Facts", "Did You Know", "Animal Facts", "Mind Blowing Facts", "Weird Facts"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    categoryFactsPincker.delegate = self
    categoryFactsPincker.dataSource = self
}
```

I would like to use this button to compare array element and UIPickerView selected for print different categories

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if categoryFactsArray[row] == 0 {

        updateInterestingFacts()
    }else if categoryFactsPincker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1){

    }
}

func updateInterestingFacts(){

    let random = interestingFactsArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(interestingFactsArray.count)))]

    //        randomFactLabel.text = random

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Random Fact", message: "\(random)", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true)

}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    return categoryFactsArray.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    return categoryFactsArray[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    categoryFactsArray[row]
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I fixed it with this code:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if Int(categoryFactsPincker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)) == 0 {
        updateInterestingFacts()
    }else if Int(categoryFactsPincker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)) == 1 {
        updateFunFacts()
    }else if Int(categoryFactsPincker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)) == 2{
        updateNutritionFacts()
    }else if Int(categoryFactsPincker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)) == 3{
        updateFunnyFacts()
    }else if Int(categoryFactsPincker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)) == 4{
        updateUnbelievableFacts()
    }else if Int(categoryFactsPincker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)) == 5{
        updateDidYouKnowFacts()
    }else if Int(categoryFactsPincker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)) == 6{
        updateAnimalFacts()
    }else if Int(categoryFactsPincker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)) == 7{
        updateMindBlowingFacts()
    }else if Int(categoryFactsPincker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)) == 8{
        updateWeirdFacts()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if categoryFactsPincker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) == 0 {
        updateInterestingFacts()
    }else{
        let categorySelected = categoryFactsArray[categoryFactsPincker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        print(categorySelected)
    }
}
```

this print should show the selected value, so you can use to compare, or whatever you need

Comment: It doesn't work Xcode return me an error. "Use of unresolved identifier 'row' " in this line if categoryFactsArray[row] == 0 {

Comment: Sorry, just copy your code, but now I make a simple change, just like you did before if the user select index 0 he call the updateInterestingFacts function, if users select a index > 0 the code print that index, you can use a variable categorySelected to pick a value selected, or categoryFactsPincker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0 to use a index selected
You can insert in array a value "Random values" if the first index don`t call this function, I don't now how you code work.